# Split string into multiple rows, to produce a dataset for further ranking by category

Tags: sql, string, r, split, rank

I have a list of items and the number of times they have been purchased. Most of these items are part of multiple categories. Some are part of a single category, other of twos, some more than two.

Now, I would like to produce a raking by each category showing the top converted items, regardless of one item appearing in multiple categories. That's perfectly fine.

Categories in the same string are separate by a `&gt;` string.

```
ItemId           Category                        PCC
5063660193       Go to Gifts                     2
24154563660193   Go to Gifts&gt;All Gifts        1
```

I would like it to become:

```
ItemId          Category      PCC
5063660193      Go to Gifts   2
24154563660193  Go to Gifts   1
24154563660193  All Gifts     1
```

Then it will be only a matter of rank them using a `rank() over()` function in SQL. 
If that's not possible in SQL I can use R.. perhaps the `reshape` function might come handy in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `R`-

```
# Your data
df <- read.table(text="ItemId           Category                        PCC
             5063660193       'Go to Gifts'                     2
             24154563660193   'Go to Gifts&gt;All Gifts'        1",
            header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


# Split Category at each "&gt;"
s <- strsplit(df$Category , "&gt;")


# Get length of each split string :length 1 if there was no "&gt;" 
l <- lapply(s , length)

# Repeat the rows where there are "&gt;"
new.df <- df[ rep(1:nrow(df) , l) , ]

# Split Category into its the compnients seperated by "&gt;"
new.df$Category <- unlist(s)
```

Comment: The only change I had to do to make it works was to use the `as.character` function in the `strsplit`: strsplit(as.character(df$Category), "&gt;")

Comment: @Gianluca; Yes Category has to be a character variable (rather than factor) in your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly simpler way using data tables.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
result <- dt[,strsplit(as.character(Category),"&gt;"),by=list(ItemId,PCC)]
setnames(result,"V1","Category")
result
#            ItemId                    PCC           Category
# 1:     5063660193                      2        Go to Gifts
# 2: 24154563660193                      1        Go to Gifts
# 3: 24154563660193                      1          All Gifts
```

Comment: Hi Howard! unfortunately I got this error message: > result <- dt[, strsplit(as.character(Category), "&gt;"), by = list(ItemId, PCC)]
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , strsplit(as.character(Category), "&gt;"),  : 
  j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group

Comment: @Gianluca; Are there duplicate id's in the untransformed data

Comment: I'd have to see the actual dataset. Can you upload and post a link? This works on your sample